# How to increment text value in SQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table in MySQL that is titled accounts, inside of accounts I have: email, first_name, last_name, etc. What I'd like to do is replace all of the email accounts to a generic value, but have each one contain an incremented value at the end. How can I do this in sql?

So for example, joeschmoe@gmail.com would turn into replacedemail1@gmail.com and the next would go from asdf@gmail.com to replacedemail2@gmail.com, and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SET @seq = 0;
UPDATE users SET email = CONCAT('replacedemail', @seq := @seq + 1, '@gmail.com')
```